# Eager Loading usig Batch Fetching

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eager-loading, batch-fetching

Is it possible to coerce JPA implemented by Hibernate into doing eager loading using Batch fetching?

You are probably wondering why I want to do such a strange thing, so let me explain.

We have two Entities `A` and `B`. There is a many to 1 relationship from `A` to `B`.

I want to load `A` entities with a search, and I want to have them fully loaded before they get returned from the repository.

But since there are lots of `A`'s and very few `B`'s all the (relevant) `B`'s will be in the second level cache. Therefore I want to avoid getting all the `B`'s every time from the database.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, a solution would be to use a NamedQuery with a `FETCH` instruction in a NamedQuery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B LEFT JOIN FETCH B.a A//will return fully loaded B instances
```

If you want to specify the Batch Size, you can use the `@BatchSize` in Hibernate (not JPA). Check [this link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-tuning-queries-using?page=0,2) for an example.

Comment: but in order to load the B instances, it will use a join, thereby bypassing the second level cache, right?

Comment: IMHO yes, as it is the case with any NamedQuery (if the query results were not cached!). But you can use `@BatchSize` without NamedQueries.